# How can I manipulate these file names in R?

Tags: r, csv

I am currently dealing with a lot of .csv files whose names are of the form "sim_data_L_m.csv" where L and m are two experimental parameters.

I have written the following code to import all of the csv files into a data frame in R, and then put all of those data frames into a list for easy indexing.

```
#Load all .csv in directory into list
dataFiles <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
N <- length(dataFiles)
dataList <- vector("list",N)
j <- 1

for(i in dataFiles) {
  #read all of the csv files
  name = gsub("-",".",i)
  name = gsub(".csv","",name)  
  i = paste(".\\",i,sep="")
  assign(name,read.csv(i, header=T))

  #add to dataList
  dataList[[j]] = assign(name,read.csv(i, header=T))
  j = j+1 
}
```

However, I recently found out that I need to extract the L and m parameters from the title name. Is there a way for me to take L and m out of the file name, and add them into another data frame with two columns (one for L and one for m), where the order of rows preserves the import order?

After I get the data in this form I know how to deal with it, I just have no clue how to extract this information from the file titles, and then how to store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` function does the trick. Notice that you may have to adjust `c(3,4)` below:

```
dataFiles <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
N <- length(dataFiles)
dataList <- vector("list",N)
j <- 1
paramlist = list()
for(i in dataFiles) {
  #read all of the csv files
  name = gsub("-",".",i)
  name = gsub(".csv","",name) 
  params = unlist(strsplit(name,split="."))[c(3,4)]
  paramlist[[j]]=params
  i = paste(".\\",i,sep="")
  assign(name,read.csv(i, header=T))

  #add to dataList
  dataList[[j]] = assign(name,read.csv(i, header=T))
  j = j+1 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What I did was I changed to split="_" and it did exactly what I want it to.

Comment: The reason it was `split="."` that you had changed all "-" to "." in line `name = gsub("-",".",i)`

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now isn't a very R-like way of managing the data. With the **tidyverse** package, it's possible to load each CSV into a nested data frame, then expand the data into a single data set with extra columns for labeling. For demonstration purposes I'm pretending that the contents of "sim_data_L_m.csv" are the mtcars data set:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.master <- tibble(fname = list.files(pattern = '*.csv')) %>% 
  separate(fname, into = c('sim', 'data', 'param1', 'param2', 'ext'), remove = F) %>% 
  select(-sim, -data, -ext) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(fname, function(x) read.csv(x)))
```

This will create a "tibble" nested data frame that looks something like:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
             fname param1 param2                   data
             <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                 <list>
1 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m <data.frame [32 x 11]>
```

Finally, using `unnest()` will expand the "data" column and repeat the labeling in all the other columns, creating a single, unified data frame:

```
data.master <- unnest(data.master, data)

# A tibble: 32 x 14
              fname param1 param2   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
              <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
 2 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
 3 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
 4 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
 5 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
 6 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
 7 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4
 8 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2
 9 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2
10 sim_data_L_m.csv      L      m  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: One could argue that `tidyverse` is even less 'R-like' ;)

Comment: I'm not really interested in learning tidyverse or changing what I already have, because what I have already works, I just needed to add another function.

Comment: Fair enough. The alternative is here for the curious, if nothing else :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how I'd do this depends on the exact make-up and pattern of the names, but this should be fairly flexible.

```
dataFiles <- c("sim_data_1_9.csv", "sim_data_2_5.csv", "sim_data_3_9.csv")
dataFiles <- sub(".csv$", "", dataFiles)

param <- strsplit(dataFiles, "_")
param <- t(sapply(param, tail, 2))

colnames(param) <- c("L", "m")
data.frame(param)
#   L m
# 1 1 9
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK using regular expressions and a separate package use `stringr`:

```
install.packages('stringr');
library(stringr);
```

You can match and extract specific groups (and nested sub groups) using `str_match`, e.g:

```
match <- str_match(c("sim_data_L_m.csv"), "(sim_data_(.*)_(.*))\\.csv");
name <- gsub("-", ".", match[1,2]);
L <- match[1,3];
m <- match[1,4];
```

`match` contains rows for each of the input strings and columns for the matching groups first column being the entire string, or `NA` if no match is found:

```
> match
     [,1]               [,2]  [,3] [,4]
[1,] "sim_data_L_m.csv" "sim_data_L_m" "L"  "m"
```